# Using web3.py to get all transaction using a specific function?

Tags: etherscan, nft, python, mint

I am trying to create a program that notifies me every time an Ethereum contract mints an NFT using a specific function.

Is this possible using web3.py?

Or am I going about this from the wrong angle?

I saw there's filters for events, but I don't think the function in the contract I want to monitor emits an event, or if it does, it would be the same event as others so I'd need to further filter it.
Is there a method to get a list of all events used in a contract?
If its not tied to an event, is there a way to find when a certain method in the contract is used?

Currently I have

```
# dependencies
import json
from web3 import Web3
import asyncio

# blockchain connection
infura_url = 'MY_INFURA_URL'
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))
    
#The Contract I'm interacting with
contract_address = '0xTHE_CONTRACT_ADDRESS'
contract_abi = json.loads('THE ABI FROM ETHER SCAN')
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=contract_abi)
```